# Lowercase or Capitalise @spec in Elixir

Tags: elixir

In `@spec` sometimes I see defined like this 
`@spec a_function(Integer, Map, List) :: {:ok, Map}`

and sometimes `@spec a_function(integer, map, list) :: {:ok, map}`

which one is the correct approach?
I can't find any concrete answer for this.

Thanks

Comment: I am not even sure if the first option is correct, but the second one definitely is and that's the common approach.

Comment: If I use the first approach, I don't get any error and everything compiles fine. That is why I though I ask.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everything would be compiled fine even if you put a garbage there. `@spec`s are used by `dialyzer` only, compiler safely ignores them while the terms are defined (e.g. are atoms) and the arity of `@spec` conforms one of the defined functions. That will work:

```
@spec call(Foo, Bar, Baz, Boo) :: BLAH
def call(p1, p2, p3, p4), do: 42
```

Only dializer will warn here, saying `42` won’t match `BLAH`.

That said, all the terms in `@spec` *must be resolved at compile time*. While they are valid atoms (`Integer`, `Map` and `List` obviously are,) the spec makes a little sense, but it won’t produce any compilation errors.

---

```
@spec a_function(integer, map, list) :: {:ok, map}
```

This notation, while better, is not correct as well. It works because the respective types are declared with *functions* `integer()`, `map()` and `list()` and while discouraged, one still can use a *function call* without parentheses. The summing up, the proper way to write a spec would be:

```
@spec a_function(integer(), map(), list()) :: {:ok, map()}
```

---

One might declare their own types with `@type` module attribute, handled by undocumented [`Typespec`](https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/blob/d0e9fd38f8883fac9ab01c70b7db45d0881d1dcd/lib/elixir/lib/kernel/typespec.ex) module:

```
defstruct MyStruct do
  @type MyStruct.t :: %MyStruct{foo: integer(), bar: atom()}
end
```

And use it later as:

```
@spec my(MyStruct.t()) :: any
def my(str), do: str.foo
```